# Convert object array to hash map using lodash

Tags: javascript, beginner, lodash.js

The use case is to convert an array of objects into a hash map where one property is the key and the other property is the value. Common case of using this is converting a "link" object in a hypermedia response into a hash map of links.

[**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/MrRampage/d4sXq/)

```
function toHashMap(data, name, value) {
    return _.zipObject(_.pluck(data, name),
                       _.pluck(data, value));
}

function toMap(data, name, value) {
    return _.reduce(data, function(acc, item) {
        acc[item[name]] = item[value];
        return acc;
    }, {});
}

var data = [
    { rel: 'link1', href: 'url1'},
    { rel: 'link2', href: 'url2'},
    { rel: 'link3', href: 'url3'},
    { rel: 'link4', href: 'url4'},
];

console.log(toHashMap(data, 'rel', 'href'));

console.log(toMap(data, 'rel', 'href'));
```

`toHashMap` appears much more readable, but less efficient. `toMap` seems to have the best efficiency at the expense of readability.

Is there a more elegant solution - i.e. both readable and efficient? I suspect that Lodash might have a function to do this already, but I haven't found anything like this after looking at the API documentation.

Comment: I've compiled the most common ways to turn an object into an array in [this lodash feature request](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/2718) _(which currently needs upvotes!)_

Answer (score 110, accepted):

I think you are looking for `_.keyBy` (or `_.indexBy` in older versions)

```
_.keyBy(data, 'rel');
```

Comment: I don't understand why is this the accepted answer since it doesn't give the same result as the exposed functions

Comment: @PauFracés See below for revised solution.

Comment: Note: Now known as `_.keyBy`(https://lodash.com/docs#keyBy).

Answer (score 43):

## Revised Solution

As per Pau Fracés comment above, here is the complete solution. The solution given by John Anderson would index all objects by the key. However, this would not create a key-value pair map.

To complete the solution of generating a full hash map, the values must be mapped to the key. Using the [mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#mapValues) function, the values can be extracted from the objects and mapped back to the key or in this case `rel`.

### Pseudo Code

1. Index all objects by the chosen key.
2. Map all values to the key.

### Code

Below is the complete code with logging enabled. For a non-logging version, remove all lines with the `tap` function.

```js
var data = [{ rel: 'link1', href: 'url1' }, 
            { rel: 'link2', href: 'url2' }, 
            { rel: 'link3', href: 'url3' },
            { rel: 'link4', href: 'url4' }];

function log(value) {
  document.getElementById("output").innerHTML += JSON.stringify(value, null, 2) + "\n"
}

var hashmap = _.chain(data)
  .keyBy('rel')

  .tap(log) // Line used just for logging

  .mapValues('href')

  .tap(log)
  
  .value();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.6.1/lodash.min.js"></script>
<pre id="output"></pre>
```

Comment: Nice solution! Personally I would go for `mapValues` instead of `transform`. With `transform` you're updating state outside the closure (it is a side-effecting function), whereas with `mapValues` you are not.

Comment: @Martijn Oh great suggestion! Makes for a much cleaner solution IMHO. I've updated the solution with your suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: @Pete Awesome! Just realized that lodash v4 renamed `indexBy` to `keyBy`

Comment: Updated to use `keyBy`

Comment: with lodash-fp this can also be done as a one-liner `flow(fpKeyBy('rel'), fpMapValues('href'))(data)` (fp-prefixed functions are fp-lodash versions)

Answer (score 22):

In ES7 it's now as simple as:

```javascript
data.reduce((acc, { rel, href }) => ({ ...acc, [rel]: href }), {});
```

(without even using Lodash).

Comment: would be great if it worked. but it doesn't seem to work! (node 5.0.0)

Comment: This is ES7, not ES2015

Comment: @ReneWooller Right, sorry. Hard to keep track of what's what when using Babel :)

Comment: That works, and it's nice to not have to have to have the lodash dependency, but damn if the lodash way isn't a million times more readable.

Comment: @Thor84no Full Lodash solution is e.g. `_.mapValues(_.keyBy(data, 'rel'), 'href')` (the accepted answer doesn't produce what the OP asked for). Readability depends on your familiarity with Lodash though.

Comment: There are more readable ways of writing it than that. The other answer for example is really clear: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/84028/84979

Comment: Whether you chain or compose is beside the point, which is that you're comparing apples and oranges. Yes, if you already use Lodash and you're familiar with these helpers, the solution using them is more readable. My aim was just to show that if you don't, it's quite simple as well.

Comment: I love this answer, lean,  efective.  I'd like to know,  when implementing it as a function,  can I pass the property names (rel and href) as arguments.  Thanks @hon2a

Comment: @digitai My point was mostly that you can easily just inline it in plain JS now. Obviously you could create an abstraction for it, but then you'd likely want to make it more efficient as well (e.g. avoid creating a new object on every pass). If key and value prop names would be external variables, you'd destructure as `{ [keyProp]: key, [valueProp]: value }`.

Answer (score 9):

A simpler way would be to use "reduce".

```
var data = [
    { rel: 'link1', href: 'url1'},
    { rel: 'link2', href: 'url2'},
    { rel: 'link3', href: 'url3'},
    { rel: 'link4', href: 'url4'},
];

var hashmap = _.reduce(data, function(hash, value) {
  var key = value['rel'];
  hash[key] = value['href'];
  return hash;
}, {});
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6txzzxq2/

With reduce you can iterate over the source array with an "accumulator" (in this case, a new object). Above we key the hash by the rel attribute with href as the value.

Comment: You could also use `.transform` to reduce the amount of code... but that's a matter of personal preference.

Comment: As stated by Martijn in a previous comment, both `.reduce` and `.transform` update state outside the closure whereas `mapValues` does not. So keep this in mind when using `.reduce`.

Comment: @Pete Updating outside state is not an inherent property of `.reduce`, but rather of the reducer itself. You can just as well use `.reduce` without side-effects (see my short answer).

Comment: @hon2a True... I one thing that bugs me about this particular `reduce` solution, though, is that 'rel' and 'href' are hardcoded into the callback. It makes it less reusable. I tried to avoid that in the original solution. The maintenance cost of a one-liner to a five-liner is much more appealing to me. As for readability, `reduce` is less fluent compared `keyBy` and `mapValues` to a non-programmer. Granted, all this is at the cost of performance and so it's not the end all of solutions. Thanks for updating to ES2015.

Comment: @Pete I'd argue that a simple use of `reduce` is actually better readable than `keyBy` + `mapValues(propNameShortcut)`, as `reduce` is a native (thus ubiquitous) method that doesn't require you to know the details of a specific (Lodash) API.

Comment: @hon2a it's a matter of personal preference, but for this specific case the question was looking for a solution using lodash, so the assumption is that the developer is using the lodash API in their project. It reminded me of a project where the architect said not to use any frameworks because developers might not know the APIs for the framework. In some cases programming with frameworks with alternative APIs can be useful and aide in maintenance and readability. It can be argued that lodash is one of these libraries, but again it's personal preference.

Comment: @Pete Sure, it's very subjective, I just wanted to include that point :) For me personally, native vs. library makes a difference in readability even though I'm using Lodash heavily.

Comment: `_.reduce(arr, (obj, item) => _.set(obj, item.Name, item.Value), {});`

Answer (score 7):

Since **lodash 4**, you can use [_.fromPairs](https://lodash.com/docs#fromPairs):

```
var data = [
    { rel: 'link1', href: 'url1'},
    { rel: 'link2', href: 'url2'},
    { rel: 'link3', href: 'url3'},
    { rel: 'link4', href: 'url4'},
];

var hashmap = _.fromPairs(data.map(function(item) {
   return [item.rel, item.href];
}));
```

Comment: Is there a way to parameterize 'rel' and 'href' outside of the `map` method to make the solution more generic?

Comment: function makePair(keyProperty, valueProperty) {
  return function(item) {
    return [item[keyProperty], item[valueProperty]];
  };
}

var hashmap = _.fromPairs(data.map(makePair('rel', 'href')));

Answer (score 3):

**With Lodash 4:**

Using `keyBy` and `mapValues`

```
_.mapValues(_.keyBy(data, 'rel'), v => v.href);
```

Or:

```
_.chain(data).keyBy('rel').mapValues(v => v.href).value();
```

Answer (score 0):

I see a lot of good answers already. I would just like to add one more answer to the list using Ramda's [indexBy](http://ramdajs.com/docs/#indexBy).

```js
const data = [{
    id: 1,
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    baz: 'lorem'
  }
];

const dataById = R.indexBy(R.prop('id'), data);
console.log(dataById)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.25.0/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

I hope it helps someone else :)

Comment: This isn't really a review of the code provided, is it?

Comment: Sorry misunderstood the use of this website. More familiar with StackOverflow :)